# Using ES6 in Node.js

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6

Iv'e been writing React apps for the last few months- and I used babel with the right presets (es2015, react) to transpile it to a bundled file.

I wish to write the server from scratch, in Node 7.9.0. Now, I know that es6 named imports are not supported yet (and if they will ever be..). Also the usage of "let" vs "var" and other es6 nice stuff.

So as far as I understand- I have no choice but staying with the "regular" features, since using babel for production is not recommended.

Is it truly the case? or there's an alternative?
And are there any resources for the "recommended" ways to write node app for the moment?

Comment: *"if they will ever be"* Yes it will. AFAIK Node 7 supports almost all ES6+ features. Have a look at http://node.green/ .

Comment: my mistake! I just saw my IDE terminal is not using the version from NVM. well, thanks for the answer and the resource!

Comment: It's still relatively easy to use babel for Node, you just need to make a `src` and `lib` folder to compile to and from. Also generally these days you'd want to use `babel-preset-env` configured for Node, rather than `es2015` directly, then it will handle whatever doesn't work on your node version.

Answer (score 0):

[ES6 support in node 7 is 99%.](http://node.green) You can use babel to add support for the harmony type imports. You can configure it in a way that it only changes the imports and everything else stays native ES6.

You can use this in production, you are not using babel on the fly, but in advance using gulp or similar.

The same goes for TypeScript.